# jQuery: Can I do $('.superset').$('.within') instead of $('.within', $('.superset'))?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Can jQuery be extended so that I can use the above syntax?

I can't figure out how to prototype whatever it is $() returns, so that I can call $().$()

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [`find()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find)

eg: `$('.superset').find('.within');`

or much simpler, `$('.superset .within');`

Answer (score 0):

> Can jQuery be extended so that I can use the above syntax?

Yes!

```
$.fn.$ = $.fn.find;
```

Now you can use `.$()`